# Globalization for ASP.NET MVC 2 Validators

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, globalization, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

Is there anyway to override the custom validation error messages from the ValidationAttributes?

Basically I need the ValidationAttributes to support globalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw a question on ScottGu's blog about it and he responded with, that is if you are using DataAnnotations. Are you?

> Yes - you can localize that today. In
>   addition to specifying the string
>   explictly you can alternatively
>   provide a resource key.  That allows
>   you to fully localize the error
>   messages.

UPDATE: I was looking at some other stuff and came across this article. Thought it might help you, or anyone else that may stumble across it.

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/11/05/Localize-ASPNET-MVC-2-DataAnnotations-validation-messages.aspx